# missing pieces of certain letters in text in Linux Mint

Tags: fonts

My problem is that as I type this message, in the second word, "problem", there are horizontal slices of missing bits in both the l and the m.

Following perusal of a similar question on the askUbuntu site, my problems persist. Here are the results of my following several suggestions (answers) that were given:

I've tried the `gksudo nvidia-settings` and `sudo fc-cache -v -f` suggestions to no avail

/etc/lsb-base yields the distribution as: debian "Linux Mint Xfce Edition"

`lspci | grep VGA` produces `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04)`

One suggestion suggested reinstalling an nVidia driver. Since I have an Intel VGA controller, is that suggestion pertinent?

I was directed to "Administration - Hardware Drivers" but no such option is in my current "Applications" menu options. I currently have an new, odd desktop (window manager?)  Another suggestion was to make an addition to xorg.conf in `/etc` or `/etc/X11`.  I have no such file, only a directory: `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Comment: Without an nvidia card messing with the nvidia driver isn't going to help. Many people are using linux with nvidia video cards and the nvidia drivers work well. I have been disappointed by several different intel video drivers.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: This smells like a dpi problem. Also try toying around with the antialiasing settings (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig` then disable it, for example).

Comment: Try to change font style from settings.

Comment: This is an old question that has probably been overtaken by events.  For anyone with a similar problem, nobody asked the obvious diagnostic questions:  Is the problem with only certain letters?  If so, are those letters always degraded and degraded in exactly the same way?  Does it make a difference where on the screen they appear?